# How to show the google profile image with ASP.Net core with identity?

Tags: c#, google-api, asp.net-core, identity

I am new to this but i am trying to retrieve google profile image using ASP.NET Core with Identity (core.identity)

Comment: So .... what code have you run? What results have you gotten?

Comment: You should post some code to go with your question. You can find information on identity with core here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins

Comment: i followed and implemented the code from the guide in the link u have posted (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins) but still don't know how to access the profile image from google plus, using core with identity.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855503/how-to-retrieve-google-profile-picture-from-logged-in-user-with-asp-net-core-ide/50057763#50057763